# Invert values for arrows in DateTimePicker

Tags: vb.net, winforms, datetimepicker

Yes, this must be the most strange request I've ever got. I have three DateTimePickers where the user can change day, month and year (in each one) by using the arrows. Left/Right is for selecting day / month / year and Up/Down for increase or decrease. Just like default.

Now the client want this to be reverse for up/down, that is, if I have the day 23 and press up, this should be 22. If the month is March and I press up, it should be February. The client's always right, huh?

Is there some default setting or something I can do for this, or do I have to write my own "logic" for this?

EDIT:
A sub question; how can i see if the current selected value is Day, Month or Year? I have this:

```
Private Sub InvertedDateTimePicker(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.KeyEventArgs) Handles _
    DTP1.KeyDown, DTP2.KeyDown, DTP3.KeyDown

    Dim dtp As DateTimePicker = sender

    If e.KeyCode = 38 Then 'UP
        '...if the current selection is day.
        'and actually i have to have -2 since the arrow up gave it +1....
        dtp.Value = dtp.Value.AddDays(-1) 
        '...if the current selection is month.
        'and actually i have to have -2 since the arrow up gave it +1....
        dtp.Value = dtp.Value.AddMonth(-1) 
    ElseIf e.KeyCode = 40 Then 'DOWN

    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: I hate clients like that.. but I think it is possible by creating your own datetimepicker, that, I just don't know how :D

Answer (score 0):

There is no built in way of doing this AFAIK.

But how about this. It works out which value has changed and inverts it:

```
Private _lastDate As Date
Private _keyDown As Boolean

Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    _lastDate = DateTimePicker1.Value
End Sub

Private Sub DateTimePicker1_KeyDown(sender As Object, e As KeyEventArgs) Handles DateTimePicker1.KeyDown
    _keyDown = True
End Sub

Private Sub DateTimePicker1_KeyUp(sender As Object, e As KeyEventArgs) Handles DateTimePicker1.KeyUp
    _keyDown = False
End Sub

Private Sub DateTimePicker1_ValueChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles DateTimePicker1.ValueChanged
    If DateTimePicker1.Value = _lastDate Then Exit Sub
    If Not _keyDown Then Exit Sub
    If _lastDate.Day <> DateTimePicker1.Value.Day Then
        'day has changed
        Dim days As Integer = DateTimePicker1.Value.Day - _lastDate.Day
        _lastDate = _lastDate.AddDays(-1 * days)
    End If
    If _lastDate.Month <> DateTimePicker1.Value.Month Then
        'month has changed 
        Dim months As Integer = DateTimePicker1.Value.Month - _lastDate.Month
        _lastDate = _lastDate.AddMonths(-1 * months)
    End If
    If _lastDate.Year <> DateTimePicker1.Value.Year Then
        'year has changed 
        Dim years As Integer = DateTimePicker1.Value.Year - _lastDate.Year
        _lastDate = _lastDate.AddYears(-1 * years)
    End If
    DateTimePicker1.Value = _lastDate
End Sub
```

If you update the value in your code you will have to set the _lastDate before updating it otherwise it will be inverted as well!

Comment: Hey, and thanks for good post. I've not tried it out, but in this case I guess it will be strange it the user clicks and selects a different day from the "calendar" ?